# Прелоадер во время расчета стоимости доставки WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня сложная логика доставки с определением положения и зон. Когда пользователь вводит адрес, начинается расчет стоимости. Пока  идёт расчет, блок просмотра заказа и кнопка "заказать" становится серыми.
Проблема в том, что с телефона этот блок не видно, он ниже зоны просмотра, пользователь не видит, что происходит какая то загрузка.
Что бы не путать пользователя - надо показать ему прелоадер.
Какой то процесс запускается, раз блок заказа становится серыми во время расчета. По такому же принципу можно сделать прелоадер, если знать, что за процесс происходит и к нему подцепиться.

Жду любых мыслей и идей. Спасибо.

Пока что вот, что нашел

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'script_update_shipping_method' );
```

````
function script_update_shipping_method() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) { //Если страница расчета
        ?>
        
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {```

                $(document.body).on('updated_checkout updated_shipping_method', function (event, xhr, data) {
                    $('.checkout-loader').css('display','flex');

                });
            });
        
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    
}
````

`updated_checkout updated_shipping_method` эти методы JQuery отвечают за обновление. Мой прелоадер под классом `.checkout-loader`  становится видимым, но как сделать его обратно `display: none` пока не нашел

Comment: Ну пока из мыслей только попытаться найти `hook` либо же `filter`, который, возможно (!), отвечает за запуск js-скрипта, который, в свою очередь, "делает" блок заказа серым. Далее мы привяжемся к этому `hook'у` (`filter'у`) и напишем свой js-скрипт, который сделает нужный вам прелоадер, Буду признателен (возможно, не только я), если выложите решение в случае его находки)

Comment: Хм... есть идея отследить изменения в DOM-поддереве через `MutationObserver` (это мы про JavaScript). То есть нам необходимо отследить изменения в классах кнопки, что становится серой, или изменения дочерних элементов во всём блоке, в котором находится кнопка. Неважно. Главное - отслеживать те изменения, которые происходят при расчёте стоимости.
Смысл в том, что у `MutationObserver` есть callback-функция. Она у нас будет запускаться только тогда, когда у кнопки удалится класс, делающий её серой. А при выполнении такая функция будет делать `display: none;` куда вам надо.

Comment: Это, наверное, далеко не самое корректное решение ДАННОЙ проблемы, но как костыль-вариант

Comment: Пока что роюсь в классе WC_ajax. Думаю, ответ где-то там

Comment: Всё еще ищу решение. Как найду - выложу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Мне подошёл вот такой вариант

```js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'awoohc_add_script_update_shipping_method' );
function awoohc_add_script_update_shipping_method() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        ?>
    
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                
                $(document.body).on('update_checkout', function () {
                    $('.checkout-loader').css('opacity','1');
                });
                
            //Срабатывает при успешном обновлении корзины. Убираем сообщение
                $(document.body).on('wc_fragments_refreshed', function () {
                        $('.checkout-loader').css('opacity','0');
                });
                
            });
        
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    
}
```

Очень помогли ребята с этой страницы: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend